# iOS Sign-in application does not work on appcenter

Tags: xcode, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I have a react-native app where build are automatic using appcenter. It was working before i update to react-native 0.62.2 (i was on 0.61.2 before).

I have this error :
`Code Signing Error: "gamefare-dev" requires a provisioning profile with the Associated Domains and Push Notifications features. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 13.4'`

I checked my certificate and redo all the upload and generation of `.p12` and `.mobileprovision` file and still the same error.

Here is a screenshot of my associated certificate in apple developer portal :
[image]

Any clue on how i may be able to solve that problem ? Building and shipping using xcode locally work.

Comment: have you found a solution? Having similar troubles ...

Comment: @wuser92 just sent what worked for me, hope it will for you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appear that automatic signin in xcode can mess up things.

What i did to solve the problem was to do manual signin (untick automatic signin in Xcode) and choose directly the right .mobileprovision and load the certificate on my mac.

This will change some stuff in your .xcodeproj file. Publish them to your git repo.

Verify by trying to publish to appstore/testflight from your mac. When working, upload the exact same file .mobileprovision in Appcenter and the certificate from your mac keychain (.p12)

Relaunch the build and it should now work.

Comment: App Center document states "App Center doesn't support signing files with special characters or symbols in the name. For example, accented characters like Ç, Ã or symbols like / "  . In my case, my provisioning profile had + sign in it. I renamed it without + sign and uploaded again and it worked.